# Question about variational autoencoder gradient

Tags: machine-learning, approximation, variational-bayes, derivative

The following is from Section 2.2 of  the [Auto-Encoding Variational Bayes](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6114v10.pdf) paper,

[image]

It says the gradient of the lower bound w.r.t $\phi$ is a bit problematic because the Monte Carlo estimator exhibits very high variance.

Why? Is it because sampling from $q_\phi(z|x)$ is of high variance? What about the gradient w.r.t $\theta$? 
$$\nabla_\theta E_{q_\phi(z|x)}[\log p_\theta(x|z)]=E_{q_\phi(z|x)}[\nabla_\theta\log p_\theta(x|z)]$$
Why is this not described as problematic?

**A note to myself**
My original confusion was that since the expectation is essentially an integral, 
$$\int_z q_\phi(z)f_\theta(z)$$
why its derivative w.r.t $\phi$ is more difficult than the derivative w.r.t $\theta$?

Now I seem to understand that the gradient w.r.t $\theta$ can be approximated approximate it by sampling from distribution $q_\phi(z)$, whereas $f_\theta(z)$ is not a distribution so we cannot do the same for $\phi$.

As an alternative we may use the [log derivative trick](https://www.coursera.org/learn/bayesian-methods-in-machine-learning/lecture/24u8X/log-derivative-trick) as mentioned in the paper, but it's usually of high variance (as mentioned in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, sampling from $q_\phi(z|x)$ is not difficult: it's just a draw from a Gaussian distribution whose mean and variance are specified by $\phi$.

The problem is specifically with marginalizing out $\phi$ using samples from $q_\phi$. Radford Neal has [a great blog post](https://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2008/08/17/the-harmonic-mean-of-the-likelihood-worst-monte-carlo-method-ever/) on why this can be a bad idea. Apart from the large (possibly infinite) variance of the estimate (assuming finite Monte Carlo samples), the estimate is also very sensitive to tiny changes in $q$'s distribution.

Comment: thank you much, I'm not very familiar with this though. do you mean marginalizing out $z$ using samples from $q_\phi$? and the problem is $q_\phi$ is too narrow (like the posterior in Radford's blog)? so it takes lots of samples to cover the regions where $q_\phi(z|x)$ is small but $q_\phi(z|x)f(z)\nabla\log q_\phi$ can be large?

Comment: Sorry, yes. Marginalizing out $z$ using samples from $q_\phi$. The gradient of $\log(q_\phi)$ with respect to $\phi$ is $1/q_\phi$, so we're in the same "harmonic mean" territory discussed in the blog post. Values in the tails that are extremely unlikely to show up in a finite sample nevertheless make huge contributions to the final result.